# Употребление притяжательных местоимений, выражающих отношение к неодушевлённому предмету

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, местоимения, местоимение

Притяжательные местоимения часто употребляются, чтобы выразить отношение, принадлежность к неодушевлённому предмету, а не к лицу.

**Я рад, что у нас теперь новый стол. Правда его цвет меня смущает.**

Однако корректно ли следующее предложение?

**Вышла новая книга. Её читатели были ошеломлены захватывающим сюжетом.**

Мне почему-то немного слух режет из-за такого употребления притяжательного местоимения или у меня просто филологическая паранойя.
Подскажите, есть ли какие-то ограничения в употреблении притяжательных местоимений, указывающих на принадлежность к неодушевлённому предмету?

Answer (score 3):

Действительно, если опустить местоимение и начать второе предложение со слова "читатели", проблема уходит. По-видимому, притяжательность создаёт здесь впечатление *постоянства действия*, и прочитавшие книгу превращаются в **постоянно читающих книгу** странных людей, вместо "прочитавших её". Правда, так можно выразиться в каком-нибудь повествовании после упоминания о книге, которую рассказчик увидел в руках у лихорадочно читающей её парочки. Как уже отмечено, с газетой всё нормально, поскольку её можно читать *систематически*.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, общих правил нет. О книге: "её обладатель" звучит корректно, а "ее читатель" режет слух и мне и Вам. О газете: "ее читатель" звучит нормально. Думаю, тут дело в сочетаемости слов *книга* и *читатель*, а не в притяжательных местоимениях.

Answer (score 1):

Считать читателей своими может газета, журнал или серия книг, первые тома которой уже вышли ранее. В этих случаях издатель рассчитывает на **постоянных** читателей, которых он и **называет своими**.

Примеры

Вышла очередная книга серийного романа известного российского фантаста. **Её читатели** по достоинству оценили яркие образы и захватывающий сюжет.

Очередной номер газеты выйдет после праздников, о чем уже оповещены **ее читатели.**